# Compatibility between IIS Smooth Streaming and Apple HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: silverlight, mobile-safari, h.264, http-live-streaming, smooth-streaming-player

It seems as though *IIS Smooth Streaming* and *Apple HTTP Live Streaming* both use similar (if not identical) underlying mechanics. In particular they both rely on segmented H.264 / MP4 files.

Is it possible to output the video segments in such a way that the same video data can be utilized by both Mobile Safari clients and Silverlight clients? If the playlist format is the only difference then this would seem easy to deal with...

Edit: or more generally -- is there a common way to segment such that this kind of adaptive HTTP streaming is possible from the same static source files to both iOS and Silverlight players (and/or even Flash too)?

Answer (score 2):

It's built in to [IIS Media Services 4.0](http://www.iis.net/media). There is an article with the details [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/854/apple-http-live-streaming-with-iis-media-services/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It sounds like IIS performs some repackaging of the data ad-hoc into .TS in that case. I'm hoping for static files that I can post straight to S3 or a CDN without the use of IIS (even though it's the IIS Smooth Streaming "format").